# What does it meant by "each row of A is a row vector of 1 length"?

Tags: matrices

A square n x n matrix is said to be orthogonal if $$AA^T=I $$. 
Show that each row of A is a row vector of 1 length.

Comment: That, individually, the entries of each row create a vector of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, this is referring to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ being 1 for each of the rows of the matrix. That is, the sums of the squares of the entries for each row come to 1.

Comment: how do I show it?

Answer (score 1):

If $A_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row then the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of $I$ is $A_iA_i^t$